# How to install Apache into a custom directory?

Tags: apache

How to install a copy of Apache into a local custom directory via Terminal (to `~/Desktop/` for example), so it can live without conflicts with another global version of Apache and I cant start and stop it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## homebrew

Consider using [homebrew](http://brew.sh) to manage a private, isolated, installation of Apache `httpd` on your Mac.

To install `brew` and Apache `httpd` on your Mac, follow the steps on [homebrew](http://brew.sh); the two main steps are:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

This will install the `brew` command line tool.

Next use [jabberwik's tap](https://github.com/jabberwik/homebrew-httpd) to install `httpd`:

```
brew tap jabberwik/homebrew-httpd
brew install httpd24
```

## MAMP

An alternative approach is to use a pre-packaged application, such as [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). Running MAMP will immediately provide Apache httpd, PHP and MySQL preconfigured and ready to use.

Comment: +1 for MAMP, absolutely love it and use it all the time.

Comment: When I run this, it doesn't include any of the apache modules so I get errors like httpd: Syntax error on line 171 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: Also that github repo is a 404